# plot multiple 2d numpy array in a single matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple  2d numpy array in a single plot.
The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import re
import sys
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Open the proper filename
try:
  filename = sys.argv[1]
  print(filename)
except IndexError:
  print("ERROR: Required filename not provided")

print("ENTER ALL ELEMENTS IN THE SAME ORDER SEPERATED BY COMMA")
elems=list((x.strip()) for x in input().split(','))
elems.insert(0, "Total")
telem=[None]*2*len(elems)
filen=[None]*2*len(elems)
for i in range(len(elems)):
  telem[2*i+1] =elems[i]+"_down"
  telem[2*i] =elems[i]+"_up"
print(elems)
# Split the file in multiple chunks
with open(filename, "r") as f:
  for key,group in it.groupby(f,lambda line: line.startswith('@target')):
    x=[];y=[]
    if not key:
        group = list(group)
        group.pop(0)
        group.pop(-1)
        for i in range(len(group)):
          x.append(group[i].split()[0])
          y.append(group[i].split()[1])
        # nx=np.array(x,dtype=float)
        # ny=np.array(y,dtype=float)
        for i in range(len(telem)):
          filen[i]=np.array(list(map(list,zip(x,y**(i%2)))),dtype=float)  #This is obviously wrong, what I want is to reverse the y axis when i is odd
          plt.plot(filen[i])
plt.show()
```

An sample input file is:

```
@target G0.S0
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.127435E-03
 -0.108715E+02  0.127829E-03
 -0.108579E+02  0.128191E-03
 -0.108443E+02  0.128502E-03
 -0.108306E+02  0.128726E-03
 -0.108170E+02  0.128838E-03
 -0.108034E+02  0.128751E-03
&
@target G0.S1
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.472694E-04
 -0.108715E+02  0.474233E-04
 -0.108579E+02  0.475837E-04
 -0.108443E+02  0.477448E-04
 -0.108306E+02  0.479052E-04
 -0.108170E+02  0.480669E-04
 -0.108034E+02  0.482279E-04
&
@target G0.S2
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.253654E-04
 -0.108715E+02  0.255956E-04
 -0.108579E+02  0.258346E-04
 -0.108443E+02  0.260825E-04
 -0.108306E+02  0.263303E-04
 -0.108170E+02  0.265781E-04
 -0.108034E+02  0.268349E-04
&
@target G1.S0
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.108786E-03
 -0.108715E+02  0.109216E-03
 -0.108579E+02  0.109651E-03
 -0.108443E+02  0.110116E-03
 -0.108306E+02  0.110552E-03
 -0.108170E+02  0.111011E-03
 -0.108034E+02  0.111489E-03
&
@target G1.S1
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.278045E-04
 -0.108715E+02  0.278711E-04
 -0.108579E+02  0.279384E-04
 -0.108443E+02  0.280050E-04
 -0.108306E+02  0.280723E-04
 -0.108170E+02  0.281395E-04
 -0.108034E+02  0.282074E-04
&
@target G1.S2
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.253058E-04
 -0.108715E+02  0.255353E-04
 -0.108579E+02  0.257745E-04
 -0.108443E+02  0.260225E-04
 -0.108306E+02  0.262617E-04
 -0.108170E+02  0.265097E-04
 -0.108034E+02  0.267666E-04
&
```

So, I want to plot all the np array in a single matplotlib as xy graph.
Also, for the odd number of list, y axis should be inverted.

But I have not managed to get this.

I am having 2 problem:
1) I cant invert the selected `y` axis
2) `matplotlib` is plotting intended x and y axis separately wrt the index, as [image]. When everything goes fine, it should look like:[image]

Kindly help

Comment: Can you please explain what you did not manage to get ?
Do you get multiple plots, one for each array ? Do you get nothing at all ?

Comment: Also, try to get the plt.show() outside of your loop, otherwise I think it will plot for every iteration.

Comment: Hi, I am having one plot for each loop.
Also, I have completely failed to revert y axis.
But, the main problem is it is plotting supposed x and y axis separately with index. wait a minute, I am updating a picture.

Comment: Took a look again, it seems that you are  using ** meaning "to the power" instead of the "*" product operator, and what you multiply by is anyway wrong.
y**(i%2) will output either 1 if i is divisible by 2 and y otherwise.
Try to replace it by  y*((i%2)*2-1)

Comment: Thanks and corrected. But how to make the plot `col1 vs col2`? As it is currently plotting `index vs col1` and `index vs col2`.